# How to fix an empty fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, youtube-data-api

I am new to Android development, trying to create my own app. It should display a particular YouTube Channel by using the YouTube Data API. I have started with the standard bottom navigation template in Android Studio and used the following project on Github for some start-up help. https://github.com/stressGC/Remake-YouTube-Android

I had to change a few things like the deprecated http call inside the code to keep it running with the new Android APKs. Everything seems fine from my point of view: I can see that the API content looks good and that each title / description / publishdate is placed in the according variables. There is also no error message in the log. When I start the emulator, the app is running fine. But as soon as I switch to the "Dashboard" fragment (where the code is placed), it is empty.

DashboardFragment.java

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {
    private static String API_KEY = "hidden"; //normaler API key ohne limits, kein oauth
    private static String CHANNEL_ID = "hidden";
    private static String CHANNEL_GET_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=date&channelId="+CHANNEL_ID+"&maxResults=20&key="+API_KEY+"";

    private RecyclerView mList_videos = null;
    private VideoPostAdapter adapter = null;
    private ArrayList<YouTubeDataModel> mListData = new ArrayList<>();

    public DashboardFragment () {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        mList_videos = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mList_videos);
        initList(mListData);
        new RequestYouTubeAPI().execute();
        return view;
    }


    private void initList(ArrayList<YouTubeDataModel> mListData) {
        mList_videos.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        adapter = new VideoPostAdapter(getActivity(), mListData);
        mList_videos.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // create asynctask to get data from youtube
    private class RequestYouTubeAPI extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            URL url = null;
            String json = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            try {
                url = new URL(CHANNEL_GET_URL);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                //HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = NetCipher.getHttpsURLConnection(url);
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String inputLine = "";
                while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(inputLine);
                }
                json = sb.toString();
                return json;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);
            if(response != null){
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.e("response", jsonObject.toString());
                    mListData = parseVideoListFromResponse(jsonObject);
                    initList(mListData);
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<YouTubeDataModel> parseVideoListFromResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        ArrayList<YouTubeDataModel> mList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (jsonObject.has("items")) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (json.has("id")) {
                        JSONObject jsonID = json.getJSONObject("id");
                        String video_id = "";
                        if (jsonID.has("videoId")) {
                            video_id = jsonID.getString("videoId");
                        }
                        if (jsonID.has("kind")) {
                            if (jsonID.getString("kind").equals("youtube#video")) {
                                YouTubeDataModel youtubeObject = new YouTubeDataModel();
                                JSONObject jsonSnippet = json.getJSONObject("snippet");
                                String title = jsonSnippet.getString("title");
                                String description = jsonSnippet.getString("description");
                                String publishedAt = jsonSnippet.getString("publishedAt");
                                String thumbnail = jsonSnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("high").getString("url");

                                youtubeObject.setTitle(title);
                                youtubeObject.setDescription(description);
                                youtubeObject.setPublishedAt(publishedAt);
                                youtubeObject.setThumbnail(thumbnail);
                                youtubeObject.setVideo_id(video_id);
                                mList.add(youtubeObject);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return mList;
    }
}
```

VideoPostAdapter.java

```
public class VideoPostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoPostAdapter.YouTubePostHolder> {

    private ArrayList<YouTubeDataModel> dataSet;
    private Context mContext = null;

    public VideoPostAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<YouTubeDataModel> dataSet) {
        this.dataSet = dataSet;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public YouTubePostHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.youtube_post_layout,parent,false);
        YouTubePostHolder postHolder = new YouTubePostHolder(view);
        return postHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull YouTubePostHolder holder, int position) {

        // set the views here
        TextView textViewTitle = holder.textViewTitle;
        TextView textViewDes = holder.textViewDes;
        TextView textViewDate = holder.textViewDate;
        ImageView ImageThumb = holder.ImageThumb;

        YouTubeDataModel object = dataSet.get(position);

        textViewTitle.setText(object.getTitle());
        textViewDes.setText(object.getDescription());
        textViewDate.setText(object.getPublishedAt());
        // image will be downloaded from url
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    public static class YouTubePostHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textViewTitle;
        TextView textViewDes;
        TextView textViewDate;
        ImageView ImageThumb;

        public YouTubePostHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textViewTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            this.textViewDes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDes);
            this.textViewDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
            this.ImageThumb = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageThumb);
        }
    }
}
```

YouTubeDataModel.java

```
public class YouTubeDataModel {
    private String title = "";
    private String description = "";
    private String publishedAt = "";
    private String thumbnail = "";

    public String getVideo_id() {
        return video_id;
    }

    public void setVideo_id(String video_id) {
        this.video_id = video_id;
    }

    private String video_id = "";

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPublishedAt() {
        return publishedAt;
    }

    public void setPublishedAt(String publishedAt) {
        this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }
}
```

youtube_post_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageThumb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="published at"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="video Title"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="22dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="video description"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mList_videos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Unfortunately I have no idea why the fragment is still empty. And without any error in Android Studio log I really hope you can help me :/

Comment: first of all check your json response if response is null then nothing display recyclerview   before you pass mListData to adpter print in log

Comment: my guess is that the problem is with parseVideoListFromResponse, try verifying that you actually reach the parseVideoListFromResponse call, and then verify that it finds the nodes correctly, perhaps if (jsonObject.has("items")) is false, which would explain that the list is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `RequestYouTubeAPI` `ASyncTask` you have this error code:

```
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Then in `onPostExecute` you have the following:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        if(response != null){
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                Log.e("response", jsonObject.toString());
                mListData = parseVideoListFromResponse(jsonObject);
                initList(mListData);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Therefore if you get an error, you `return null` and if `onPostExecute` is given a  `null` response it does nothing.

So this one place you could have an error and therefore a blank fragment.

---

Before you fix this, you can prove this is happening like so:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        if(response == null){
            Log.e("TUT", "We did not get a response, not updating the UI.");
        } else {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                Log.e("response", jsonObject.toString());
                mListData = parseVideoListFromResponse(jsonObject);
                initList(mListData);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

You can fix this two ways:

in `doInBackground` change the catch to this:

```
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TUT", "error", e);
            // Change this JSON to match what the parse expects, so you can show an error on the UI
            return "{\"yourJson\":\"error!\"}";
        }
```

or `onPostExecute`:

```
        if(response == null){
            List errorList = new ArrayList();
            // Change this data model to show an error case to the UI
            errorList.add(new YouTubeDataModel("Error");
            mListData = errorList;
            initList(mListData);
        } else {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                Log.e("response", jsonObject.toString());
                mListData = parseVideoListFromResponse(jsonObject);
                initList(mListData);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Hope that helps, there may be other errors in the code but this is one case that can happen if there is a problem with the API, the Json, the authorization, the internet etc.

Comment: I will highlight this as the answer because it was the most helpful one in this case. I have found the mistake with the debugger but your ideas pushed me in the right direction. In the end I just mixed up mList and mListData in my code. Well, sorry for my late response and thank you all for your very fast feedback. It was my first question here and I was really surprised!